# Where are the reviews?

Tags: support

Ever since I hit 10k rep, I have a number of "posts awaiting review", but when I click on it, there are none to review:

[image]

Clicking on the Meta Reviews, doesn't show any posts waiting for review either.

Is this a glitch or am I missing something?

Comment: See [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11778/review-queue-bug) as well

Comment: Well there's another bug, I vote to close my own question and I then also have to click "that solved my question"...